# opencv videocapture and read doesnt retrieve all frames. Returns incorrect number of frames

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, opencv

I have a mp4 video which is 29 minutes long with 1536x2304 resolution. What I am trying do is to create a dataloader which ingest mp4 files and feeds to a CNN, but to do so I need to use opencv to retrieve the frames. When I use cap = cv.VideoCapture("mp4 file") and ret, frame = cap.read(), I only receive about 40 frames.

Since the Video is 29 min long, and it is 18fps, the number of frames I expect is around 31320 frames, but I only get 40. Really confused, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your counting code?

Comment: I've observed mp4 files with broken frames which deliver empfy frames and false returnCode but you can just continue trying to read frames and after some while you will get new ones. Typically I allow up to 100 or 200 trials.

Answer (score 1):

As you specified that you used the line `ret, frame = cap.read()` to count the number of frames, I would assume that you are using a `while` loop with a condition of when to `break`.

Have you considered that the `while` loop may have ended due to an issue unrelated to the number of frames in the `VideoCapture` object? Or you may have called the `cap.read()` method multiple times per increment to the variable you used to count the frames with.

The proper way to get the number of frames in a video using OpenCV would be:

```
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture("file.mp4")
count = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

print(count)
```

*(Note: If you get the output `0`, then the filename specified likely couldn't be found and would need to be corrected.)*